# form class not found zend 2.3

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to create a simple form using zendform here is the code of form class:

```
<?php
namespace admin\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class Addstudent extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        // we want to ignore the name passed
        parent::__construct('addstudent');


        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'fio',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Фио',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'gender',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Пол',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '0' => 'М',
                    '1' => 'Ж',
                ),

            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'birthdate',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Дата рождения',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'edge',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Возраст',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'university',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Вуз',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'group',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Группа',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'department',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Факультет',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'grate',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Курс',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '0' => '1',
                    '1' => '2',
                    '2' => '3',
                    '3' => '4',
                    '4' => '5',
                    '5' => '6',

                ),

            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'enterence',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'год поступления',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'financesource',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Курс',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '0' => 'Бюджет',
                    '1' => 'Контракт',

                ),

            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'studyform',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Форма обучения',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '0' => 'Дневная',
                    '1' => 'Заочная',

                ),

            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'homeaddress',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Домашний адрес',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'actualaddress',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Фактический адрес',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'phone',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Телефон',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'workplace',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Место работы',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'services',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'услуги',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'сохранить',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

But then I try to show it controller shows fatal error class Addstudent not found. here is how I imported it to a controller

```
use admin\Model\Admin;
use admin\form\Addstudent;
```

And here is an action

```
public function addstudentAction()
{

    $form = new Addstudent();
    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Сохранить');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $admin = new Admin();
        $form->setInputFilter($admin->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $admin->exchangeArray($form->getData());
           // $this->getAlbumTable()->saveAlbum($album);

            // Redirect to list of albums
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin');
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form);


  //  return array();
}
```

form file is located in module/admin/src/admin/form/addstudent.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything beneath your `src` folder should use an initial upper case letter, so `module/admin/src/admin/form/addstudent.php` should be `module/admin/src/Admin/Form/Addstudent.php` and so on.

Then you should change your namespace declarations to match this, i.e. `namespace Admin\Form;` and `use Admin\Form\Addstudent;`.

At the moment you are not being consistent about case (e.g. you declare `namespace admin\Form;` but have `use admin\form\Addstudent;` in your controller) which is likely the cause of your issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had the very same problem. The autoloader didn't work. My project hasn't a lot of forms, so I have put this into my Bootstrap:

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
   require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/forms/Contact.php';
   require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/forms/Participant.php';
}
```

But few days ago I solved my problem. The Zend library of mine wasn't in the project's folder "library", but few adresaries above(I changed the paths in settings and index.php). Since I moved it into project's folder "library", autoloader seems to be working fine.

Do you have this problem with other forms/tables? Cause I did.

Comment: This is my first form on zend. Sorry where is bootstrap file located in zend 2?

Comment: In 'application' folder is file Bootstrap.php

Comment: I just read the documentation and found that where is no such file in zend 2. What I did i added that require in module.php method onbootstrap and got the following error: Route with name "Admin\Controller\AdminController" not found

Comment: Sorry for your wasted time. I thought it's same in zend 1 & 2. When you echo your APPLICATION_PATH, what does it returns? The 'solution' with require is like using ducktape tho, it should autoload. Sorry that I can't provide you better one.

Comment: Everythin is ok. At list it gives different error now. I just don't know is it related to that require or not... but will see. Thank you for helping me.